# Обработать объект внутри массива с минимальной номером

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Необходимо преобразовать массив в объект таким образом, чтобы в качестве ключей были `type`, а в качестве их значений - `min` и `max` из соответствующих объектов с наименьшим `min` и `name` из родительского объекта.

Пример исходного массива:

```js
[{
    name: "test",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 40,
        max: 48
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 55,
        max: 61
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 46,
        max: 42
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 61,
        max: 100
      },
      {
        type: "Тяжёлый",
        min: 220,
        max: 200
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Результирующий объект:

```js
{
  "Лёгкий": {
    name: "test",
    min: 40,
    max: 48
  },
  "Средний": {
    name: "test",
    min: 55,
    max: 61
  },
  "Тяжёлый": {
    name: "test2",
    min: 220,
    max: 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует огромное количество способов, решаемых данную задачу. Один из них - воспользоваться методами [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) и [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) массивов без прибегания к помощи сторонних библиотек:

```js
const src = [{
    name: "test",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 40,
        max: 48
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 55,
        max: 61
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 46,
        max: 42
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 61,
        max: 100
      },
      {
        type: "Тяжёлый",
        min: 220,
        max: 200
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result = src.reduce((acc, v) => {
  v.types.forEach(t => {
    if (acc[t.type] && acc[t.type].min < t.min) {
      return
    }

    acc[t.type] = {
      name: v.name,
      min: t.min,
      max: t.max,
    }
  })

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```